# AWS - How to use privatehosted zone URL instead of hostname for connecting RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-route53

Mysql RDS is sitting in Private subnet, I use below string to connect Mysql.

```
mysql -uroot-h<HOSTNAME>.rds.amazonaws.com -p<PWD>
```

Now I have created a private hosted zone for db.example.com in route53 with RDS hostname as a cname record.

if I tried to use the below string, I'm getting below error.

```css
mysql -u root -hread.db.devtest.example.com -p<PWD>
```

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host
```

Anyone configured above setup and found a way to connect RDS through private hosted URL as hostname?? TIA..

Note: It worked.. Already had dns resolution and dns hostname enabled in the custom VPC.. I was trying to connect DB from my local through VPN, actually dns resolution wont work on resources that sitting other side of VPN. I logged into one of the instance in the VPC and tried to connect with custom hostname that I created and it's working. Thanks a lot for your inputs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-private-hosted-zones

Comment: Can you do a `dig cname record` and paste what do you get? I am not sure what do you mean by hostname as a cname record. You mean you created a record within the newly created hosted zone by a name (e.g `my-db.myprivatezone`) with cname pointing the aws given url for the db?

Comment: yes, created a cname which is pointing the aws given url for the db.

Comment: Have you checked with dig if the new dns name is risolvable?

Comment: be sure to review VPC settings required for hosted zones (you may need to build a custom VPC): https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-enable-private-hosted-zone/

Comment: @Riz Please find below results for dig command.                                                                 ; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> db.devtest.xxxxxx.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 1554
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;db.devtest.xxxxxx.com. IN A

;; Query time: 74 msec
;; SERVER: 192.1xx.0.1#53(192.1xx.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 01 09:56:59 IST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43

Comment: @ahfx Created custom VPC and already using private hosted zone for other purposes. It just that db connection is not established with private hosted zone URL.

Comment: is the ec2 instance in the same vpc as the RDS server?  Does the ec2 instance have a private hostname associated with it?  Can it resolve other hosts using private names?

Comment: @gview yes, ec2 instance is in the same VPC and has private IP. Not sure how to verify whether it can resolve other hosts using private names.

Comment: Check this https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-troubleshoot-nxdomain-responses/

Comment: It has a private IP, but does it have an associated hostname in the private dns zone?

Comment: Hey All. it worked.. Already had dns resolution and dns hostname enabled in the custom VPC.. I was trying from my local with VPN, actually dns resolution wont work on resources that sitting other side of VPN.


I logged to one of the instance in the VPC and tried to connect with custom hostname it's working.



Thanks a lot for your inputs.